# 2d barcode recognizer

Tags: barcode, image-recognition

Is there a free library for recognizing a 2d barcode from an image? ..or a freeware or anything ?
I don't want any hardware equipments.

Comment: Please, clarify, what particular 2d barcode do you want to recognize: QRCode, DataMatrix, smth else?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified a programming language or platform, but you might want to take a look at [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/).

Comment: i dont know what type of the 2d barcode ..it came behind an identification card i have..and about programming lang and platform (c# windows)  i will check that link thnx alot